# Jquery show function issue - not animating or showing the hidden paragraph, why

Tags: jquery, animation, show

Here is the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                                                                 
<head>                                                                  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "sample1.css"></link>       
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#testing").click(function() { 
                $("#testing2").show("slow");  
            });
        });  
    </script>                                                                  
</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                   
    <a id = "testing" href="">Link</a>      
    <p id = "testing2"> 
        lksjflksjdlkflskdjflksjdflkjslkjdflk
        lsdkflksjgliowtjlskdfjlskdfjlskgs
        lksjlk,.x,cmlkvjlkjlwkeoltklfnjsklkj
        lksjf.m,.jlkjoliwekjtlkjgkjjlkjlkjll
        llvalkiwujoitjlkgskjdkgjlsd,fjlsllll
    </p>
</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
#testing
{
    width:          100px;
    height:         50px;
    border:         1px solid;
    font-size:      22px;
    display:        block;
    text-align:     center;
    padding:        25px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#testing2
{
    display:        none; 
    width:          270px;
    height:         300px;
    background:     yellow;
    border:         1px solid;
}
```

For some reason, when i click the link, it does not show the paragraph #testing2, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/2mC3C/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `return false;` inside your click function. As good practice you should make the link to # eg href="#" as well

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#testing").click(function(){ 
       $("#testing2").show("slow");
       return false;
    });
});
```